# Check if float in dataseries column is within .200 of another float in another column

Tags: python, pandas

sorry if this question has been answered before but I have looked through several previously answered questions and can't figure it out for my self.

So far I have:

```
df = pd.read_csv("CSVFILE.csv") 
df_close = pd.DataFrame(df.Close)
```

My csv file looks like:

```
Open    High    Low     Close   Volume
133.795 137.610 132.905 137.275 165822.375
```

I want to check if the Open is within .200 of the close.
I.e: if Open is 133.795 and Close is between 133.995 and 133.595 I want the program to tell me.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this too:
    import numpy as np

```
df.loc[:,'new_column'] = np.where((df['Open'] <= df['Close'] + 0.2) & (df['Open'] >= df['Close'] - 0.2), 'In range', 'Not in range')
```

To filter the values in range only:

```
df[df['new_column'] == 'In range']


Open    High    Low Close   Volume  new_column
1   133.795 137.61  132.905 133.994 165822.375  In range
2   133.795 137.61  132.905 133.596 165822.375  In range
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
print (df)
      Open    High      Low    Close      Volume
0  133.795  137.61  132.905  137.275  165822.375
1  133.795  137.61  132.905  133.994  165822.375
2  133.795  137.61  132.905  133.596  165822.375

m = df['Close'].between(df['Open'] - .2, df['Open'] + .2)
print (m)
0    False
1     True
2     True
dtype: bool
```

Or:

```
a = df['Open'] - .2
b = df['Open'] + .2
m = (df['Close'] >= a ) & (df['Close'] <= b)
```